# Why is my foreach loop not working as expected?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to PHP development, but I'd like to think I'm picking it up at a rapid pace, but I hit a bit of a problem when I moved from XAMPP to a real host. I'm trying to do something like this.

```
$cast_list = mysqli_query($dblink, $sql);
foreach ($cast_list as $role)
{
    echo "<tr><td width='50%'>".$role['appeared_as']."</td>";
}
```

It works on XAMPP which I have installed on my home PC, but it does not work on the hosting I've arranged to test with. The actual query is working perfectly, so that's not the problem. I can see the correct results in PHPMyAdmin, on XAMPP and when I change the code as follows.

```
$cast_list = mysqli_query($dblink, $sql);
$y = mysqli_num_rows($cast_list);
for ($x = 0; $x <$y; $x++)
{
    $role = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cast_list);
    echo "<tr><td width='50%'>".$role['appeared_as']."</td>";
}
```

The second code block will produce the desired effect. The first code block will apparently iterate 5 times, but will not contain any meaningful data. In fact a `var_dump($role)` for the first code block reveals that it is `NULL`.

I can just adapt to this if need be, but maybe there's a logical reason why `foreach` isn't working properly for me?

Comment: You cannot iterate over mysqli_query return, you have to use `$roles= mysqli_fetch_assoc($cast_list)` if you want to do a foreach on `$roles`.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://php.net/mysqli_query).

Answer (score 4):

`mysqli_query()` doesn't return an array or array object that you can use with foreach(). The return type of mysqli_query() is a resource. You fetch from it in a loop, like your second solution.

It's simpler to use while() instead of for():

```
$cast_list = mysqli_query($dblink, $sql);
while ($role = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cast_list)) {
    echo "<tr><td width='50%'>".$role['appeared_as']."</td>";
}
```

The loop will terminate automatically when the row fetched is NULL at the end of the result set. You don't need to know the number of rows before the loop.

---

Re your comment:

After [looking up some facts](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), I have to admit that my answer above isn't fully true. Or isn't true for some versions of PHP.

In PHP 5.4, a mysqli_result resource added `Iterator` functionality, you actually *can* use it in a `foreach()`. But your host apparently uses an older version of PHP.

The best practice is to develop on the same version of *all* software that you will deploy to, so you aren't caught by this sort of surprise.

Comment: Would you mind explaining to my why using foreach worked on XAMPP? I understand what you're saying, and the code you've provided is a nice and neat way which I intend to adopt. I just am confused why my original version seemed to work until I tested it on a real host.